# Writing query to return rows only if they contain every item from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have a relatively complex problem I'm trying to solve with a query and I'm wondering if it can be done with a single query.

For a simple example I have tables for:

- `authors` (id, firstname, lastname, effective_date, retirement_date)
- `articles` (id, author_id, title, content)
- `recipients` (id, name, email)
- `subscriptions` (author_id, email)

Subscriptions for example looks like:

```
// Subscriptions table

author_id   email
1           'johnsmith@gmail.com'
1           'jackymoon@gmail.com'
2           'edmonix@gmail.com'
1           'louredwood@gmail.com'
2           'louredwood@gmail.com'
3           'louredwood@gmail.com'
4           'louredwood@gmail.com'
```

etc...

I want to return a list of emails where an email is only returned if the number of times it occurs in the table is equal to a second query.

```
query_1 = SELECT email FROM recipients
          WHERE email has an entry for every author returned from query_2...

query_2 = SELECT * FROM authors
          WHERE current_date BETWEEN effective_date AND retirement_date
```

I've only had to do simple queries so far, so any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution would be to use subqueries in the WHERE clause.

> SELECT .... WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions s WHERE s.email
> = rp.email) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM authors)

(find rp records where number of subscriptions equals number of authors)
Or similar combination - for example *find all rp records where number of not subscribed authors equals 0*